# Azure VM Availibilty Zone and Load Balancing

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have single instance VM. I plan to add it to Availability Zones. If I do that, there we will be copy of the same machine in multiple Zone. My understanding is that Azure will keep the VMs in Sync. Is this true? Also isn't it mandatory to add a load balancer then? Or will Azure take care of that as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this learning topic [Build a scalable application with virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/build-app-with-scale-sets/) by Microsoft. As far as I understand, VMs are sync in terms of administration (network configuration, disks, state...) but what you have inside must be configured manually. What Microsoft propose is to use a [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/build-app-with-scale-sets/6-install-update-applications-virtual-machine-scale-sets).

On the other hand, if your VMs is waiting for requests, you need a load balancer in charge of sending request to different VMs